# login and signup tab does not work xml

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to create login and signup tab on the same page. so everytime I press signup on the login screen, it change to the signup screen as expected, so does the signup screen. On the signup screen, everytime I press the login tab, it works too. But on the login screen, everytime I press login, it goes to signup screen but I want it to stay on login screen. The weird thing is that everytime I press signup, it stays on the signup screen . Can anyone help? any help would be appreciated.

Android classes

SignUpScreen.java

```
 final Intent i = new Intent(SignUpScreen.this, LoginScreen.class);
    TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
            SignUpScreen.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

my LoginScreen.java

```
final Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,SignUpScreen.class);
    TextView c = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);

    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            setContentView(R.layout.sign_up_screen);
            LoginScreen.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: show your full code

Comment: can you share your complete code for better understanding??

Comment: That is absolutely wrong. `setContentView()` should be called in `onCreate()` while initializing the view of your activity. You can't call in `onClickListener`. Better try with activity or fragment,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create two activity one for login and another for signup, in login activity you have to give login form and two button one for login and one for signup.
and make the login activity as your launcher activity. on clicking the signup button just call the signup activity by using intent

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

```
private EditText mEmail;
private EditText mPassword;

Button btn_login,btn_signup;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                uid = mEmailView.getText().toString();
                pwd = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

                if(uid.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    mEmailView.setError("Please enter user id");
                }else if(pwd.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    mPasswordView.setError("Please enter password");
                }else  {
                    //do whaterver you want to do after login
                }

        }
    });

            btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Signup.class);
                    startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

and in Signup page when you signup the user successfully redirect him to the login page by using  intent

Intent i=new Intent(Signup.this,LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

or you can redirect him into the other activity

Answer (score 0):

Inside `setOnClickListener`, why you have given `setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);`
    Actually in `onCreate` only, `setContentView` should be present.

Better your full code will help to guide.

Comment: you should comment these kind of suggestion as this is not a answer and you have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 0):

try above code for SignUpScreen.java

```
TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(SignUpScreen.this, LoginScreen.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

and for LoginScreen.java

```
TextView c = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);

c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,SignUpScreen.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call setContentView in onCreate method and do something like this :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

   if(forLoginScreen) {
     setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
   }else {
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up_screen);
   }

}
```